# MassTransit - Limit which messages get processed concurrently in multi-consumer setup

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Currently, I have a single windows service using RabbitMQ to handle messages async from a web app. This service uses an entity ID on the message to lookup what entity needs to be processed. The message currently does not indicate what should be done to the entity since this is already provided by an internal action log. To help with moving to a multiple competing consumer setup, I was looking at implementing MassTransit over RabbitMQ.

I'm looking at how to prevent multiple messages with the same entity ID from being processed at the same time on different consumers. Is there anything built into MassTransit that would allow me to handle this situation or a suggestion/resource on how to handle?

I've looked at the latest filter and the green pipes partition filter. Either these do not do what I want or I've configured it incorrectly in my test solution. I've also thought about putting a lock on the entity so that the 2nd+ concurrent attempt to process the entity will wait until this first is done, but I really rather not tie up one or more consumers waiting if I don't have too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partitioner should do exactly what you need, given you specify the key provider so that it returns the same identifier for the same entities.

This unit test shows how the partitioner is setup:
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Tests/Pipeline/PartitionByKey_Specs.cs

The key being:

```
configurator.Consumer(() => new PartitionedConsumer(_completed), x =>
{
    x.Message<PartitionedMessage>(m =>
    {
        m.UsePartitioner(8, context => context.Message.CorrelationId);
    });
});
```